# Calculate % based on Total Events for Event Action in Google data studio

Tags: google-analytics, formula, metrics, calculated-field, looker-studio

I just started to use Google Data Studio for creating a dashboard to get more insights in our data. Now I've created the table you can see below.

[image: Table in Google Data Studio]

This is the data from the trackers on our video's. The first event action *videotrackerStart* is the total amount of people who started watching the video. What I want to do is calculate what percentage the rest of the event actions is from the *videotrackerStart* event.

So for example `(176,985 / 222,468) * 100 = 79.5%` and that for each action.

The problem I face, is that I don't know how to (if it is even possible) save the Total Events for *videotrackerStart* in a variable and use that value to create a new metric.

Does anyone know how I could get this done? I hope the question is clear, please let me know if not.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Edit (2017/10/26): Percentage of total is now supported in Data Studio using [Analytics Functions](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7512288#apply-analytical-functions).

Original: Percentage of total for a metric is not yet supported in tables in Data Studio. You can [Request this feature](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=196095&template=0) or vote for the feature in the existing [feature request list](https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/578413).

To represent the same information visually you can try using barcharts.